# React Native,not correct working onPress

Tags: javascript, react-native

guys i have a problem with event onPress!If i change TextInput value function _find() working,but clicking on button event not working.
Error in console:"Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `onPress` is marked as required in `Button`, but its value is `undefined`.
"

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, TextInput, View,StyleSheet,Button } from 'react-native';


export default class inputText extends Component {
  _find(){
    fetch('https://google.com')
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((text)=>{ console.debug(text) })
    
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: null};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{margin: 20}}>
        <TextInput
          style = {styles.searchInput}
          placeholder="Type here to search"
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
        />
         <Button
          onPress={this._find()}
          title='Find'
          color="#841584"
          accessibilityLabel="on"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  searchInput:{
    fontSize:20,
    paddingTop:20,
    paddingBottom:20
   
    
  }
})

// skip this line if using Create React Native App
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => inputText);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omit the parenthesis, otherwise it'll execute the function instead of passing it as a callback:

```
onPress={this._find}
```

You will also need to bind the method to `this` in `constructor` if you need to access the class instance in `_find`:

```
constructor(props) {
  ...
  this._find = this._find.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to call the method *_find_* when the button is pressed. What you are actually doing, though, is calling the method when the component is rendered and then assigning the result of that method call (which is *undefined*) to the *onClick* handler.

You can fix this by turning the value for the *onClick* prop into an anonymous arrow function, like this:

```
<Button
  onPress={() => this._find()}
  title='Find'
  color="#841584"
  accessibilityLabel="on"
/>
```